# How to make menu work with ngRoute on AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute

How to make menu work like normal menues in Online shops? I`ve got a menu,when I click on element it should redirect me to myshop.com/food where food depends on what is clicked in menu.It should work with ngRoute,but how to make my products appear there? maybe somehow it can make http call to my object?

ngRoute:

```
mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/pizza", {
    templateUrl: "food.html"
}).otherwise({
    templateUrl: "food.html"
});
```

Menu code:

`<li><a href="#!pizza">Pizza</a></li>
<li><a href="#!burgers">Burgers</a></li>
         <ng-view></ng-view>`

food.html

```
   <div class="food-show-block">
            <div class="block-container">
                <div class="block item-block food-block" id="foodBlock" ng-repeat="product in food.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage)) | filter:search" ng-mouseenter="showBasket=true" ng-mouseleave="showBasket=false">
                    <div class="basket" ng-show="showBasket"> <i class=" fa fa-shopping-basket fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i> </div>
                    <a href="#"> <img src="{{product.imageLink}}" alt="">
                        <div class="details">
                            <p class="price">{{product.price}}грн</p>
                            <p class="name"> {{product.name}}</p>

                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: there are a few problems with this code; you start off with saying you want `/food` but you show routes `/pizza` and otherwise, where ***both routes are exactly the same***.  it seems like you need to do a bit more research into what it is you are trying to do, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using *Controllers*

With the `$routeProvider` you can also define a controller for each `view`, like this :

```
mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/pizza", {
    templateUrl: "food.html",
    controller : "pizzaCtrl"
}).otherwise({
    templateUrl: "food.html",
    controller : "foodCtrl"
});
```

In your `controller` ***write the logic*** like calling an `http` service

```
mainApp.controller('foodCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("httpGetUrl")
      .then(function(response) {
       $scope.yourObject = response.data;//response from get
       });    
});
```

Comment: and it will call http by clicking on menu link?